# array_unique remove duplicate values in span

Tags: php, arrays

Consider the following array..

```
$a = array(
  'a' => 'red',
  'b' => 'green',
  'c' => 'red'
);
print_r(array_unique($a));
```

You would get

> Array ( [a] => red [b] => green )

I have an array that uses `<span>` in the values to give them a class.

```
$a = array(
  'a' => '<span class="available">red</span>',
  'b' => '<span class="available">green</span>',
  'c' => '<span class="booked">red</span>'
);
print_r(array_unique($a));
```

You get

> Array ( [a] => red [b] => green [c] => red )

This is because with the classes, they are no longer unique.

Is there a way to use array_unique using only a part of the string? Perhaps using strip tags on the value first?

Comment: Yes, either strip the formatting to extract just the values you want, or consider regex.

Comment: And how would one use that with array_unique? Could you possibly provide an example for me? The only parameter i can find is sortingtype

Comment: Well, I already answered, but which _red_ should it return?  _Available_ or _Booked_?

Comment: Just the first red, your answer worked perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So `strip_tags()` was a good thought:

```
$result = array_intersect_key($a, array_unique(array_map('strip_tags', $a)));
```

- Map the array to strip the tags with `array_map()`
- Get the unique values with `array_unique()`
- Get elements from the original array that have common keys with the unique array with `array_intersect_key()`

This yields:

```
Array
(
    [a] => <span class="available">red</span>
    [b] => <span class="available">green</span>
)
```

So as you can see, it will return the first value for *red*.

Answer (score 0):

If you want get unique values from your  span tags, you can as you said, first simply strip tags and then print unique values.

```
$a = array(
  'a' => '<span class="available">red</span>',
  'b' => '<span class="available">green</span>',
  'c' => '<span class="booked">red</span>'
);


foreach ($a as $val) {
    $b[] = strip_tags($val);
}


print_r( array_unique($b) );
```